# Strange output with large vectors

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I was solving AMR10G problem on spoj. The problem is just about sorting and is trivial to implement with arrays. I'm a beginner in STL and just to get familiar with STL i was trying to solve it with using some vectors. The code runs fine with small sizes of vector but with large sizes( can be 20,000 in the problem) it prints all 0s. Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    int T;
    cin>>T;
    while(T--){
        int N, k, i;
        cin>>N >> k;
        //***********************************************************
        vector<int> ar(N);//problem seems to be here when N ~ 20000
        //***********************************************************
        for(i = 0; i<N; i++) scanf("%d",&ar[i]);

        sort(ar.begin(),ar.end());

        //calculate smallest difference
        int small = ar[k-1] - ar[0];
        for(i = k-1; i<N; i++){
            int temp;
            if( temp = ar[i] - ar[i-k+1] < small) small = temp;
        }
        cout<<small <<endl;//print smallest difference
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I changed the type to array it ran perfectly fine. What is the problem with using vectors?

Comment: It would be good if you can provide or describe a data set that generates the problem

Comment: @MattMcNabb I cant have data set since it is problem from SPOJ. But it seemed to me that changing from vector to array solved my problem.

Comment: Link of the problem http://www.spoj.com/problems/AMR10G/

Comment: "changing from vector to array solved my problem." most likely indicates that you are accessing out of bounds of the array/vector, but in the array case it happens to read random values that don't affect the result

Comment: I think there's a fundamental error in your algorithm. If you have a sorted sequence (say `1 5 7 11`) then the smallest difference must be between adjacent elements. It can't be `7-1` because there is a `5` in between.  But I might be mistaken because I don't know what `k` does. You may want to choose more explicit names for variables. `i` is fine for a loop index, and `N` for size is still reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a lack of error checking:

- Check that `cin >> N >> k` succeeded.
- Check that each `scanf` succeeded.
- Check `k -1` is within range of the array bounds.

Any of those failures could cause your problem.

There is also a logic error on this line:

```
if( temp = ar[i] - ar[i-k+1] < small) small = temp;
```

The control expression is parsed as `temp = (ar[i] - ar[i-k+1] < small)`, so this line will set `small = 1` if `ar[i] - ar[i-k+1] < small` and do nothing otherwise. You probably meant `(temp = ar[i] - ar[i-k+1]) < small)`.

Comment: I question your claim "the code runs fine with arrays" given that the output must have been all zeroes or ones when presumably you expected a variety of output

Comment: I doubt what you say about parsing. I ran the above code on the test cases provided in the problem and it gave the right output.

Comment: The test case i tried it on -                                                                             3 
3 1 
2 5 4  
3 2 
5 2 4  
3 3 
2 5 4

Comment: And i got output 0 1 3 as expected. According to you it should be a variation of 0 and 1.

Comment: @AbhilashSingh the `3` happens because it was the starting distance (which you set with `int small = ar[k-1] - ar[0];` before the loop) and none of the other distances in the loop were smaller. (in fact there are no other distances, this is the last one).

Comment: I missed that. I appreciate your help.